# How to isolate VMs with internet exposed websites on my home network?

Tags: web-application, network, server, virtualization

I want to host some websites served from an isolated VM which is on my home network through port forwarding.

Although I believe this is reasonably safe, I want to physically segment internet-exposed VMs from my main home network. What is the best way to do this in a virtualized setup? I am using proxmox with a bridged network model.

Comment: We can't comment on hardware recommendations, unfortunately.

Comment: "I believe this is reasonably safe" -- no it is not.

Comment: You say that the VM is "isolated", but what does that mean? Where is this VM running? What can be done to isolate the host?

Comment: Buy a raspberry pi or similar and put it on the guest network. Cloud-hosted options are incredibly cheap, too.

Comment: I second to a cloud-hosted option. I run small servers for less than a dollar per month.

Answer (score 0):

You need a kind of DMZ network. If you have a somewhat capable modem, you can achieve simple isolation by moving the home network to a different subnet. If you want to take it a step further, you can use a VM to install a firewall and separate the networks. You can even handle port forwarding processes from there.

Comment: If the server VM is on a host that is also on the home network, "moving to another subnet" needs a lot more explanation. And you might want to explain how the VM firewall would work. This answer could use more detail, but you might need more details from the OP first.